# read the files in Directory in PowerShell scripting

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell scripting. Now, I want to create a script that returns all the `packages.config` in a folder. Then read all the files return and write them on a file.

Currently, I have a script that returns all the `packages.config` file as shown below:

```
$files = Get-Childitem -Path C:\test -Include packages.config -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

The script above will return all the directories the `packages.config` is found. Now for every directory, I want to get the full directory location and write it in a file `found.txt` and at the same time read the `packages.config` in the directory and write its content in the `found.txt`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, not sure if you want a result as plain text or an actual object.

```
$files = Get-Childitem -Path C:\test -Filter packages.config -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$result = foreach($file in $files)
{
    '=' * 100
    ''
    '- Absolute Path: {0}' -f $file.FullName
    '- File Content:'
    ''
    Get-Content $file.FullName -Raw
    ''
}

$result | Out-File 'path\to\result.txt'
```

Output should look something like this:

```
===================================================...

- Absolute Path: D:\testing\file1.txt
- File Content:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing ...

===================================================...

- Absolute Path: D:\testing\file2.txt
- File Content:

Maecenas massa turpis, mattis et eleifend ac, venen...

===================================================...

- Absolute Path: D:\testing\file3.txt
- File Content:

Nulla facilisis vulputate ultrices. Fusce ut mi nis...
```